Tizen system Date and time
I am using samsung tizen tv, but there is an issue with date and time, when my device is off for certain period of time, the date and time is getting reset.
Is there any other way for setting correct date and time with current date and time, as I am getting issues with ntp functionality for socket connection.
Is there any other approach for setting correct date and time through app itself?
So basically I don't want to relay on system time so any other approach for setting correct date and time.
